# How do you find out the .NET version of a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0, service

There are a lot of questions here about finding out what .NET framework is installed. **I know that I have upto .NET v4.6.1 installed.**

**I want to find out what version of .NET a service is built on.**

Let's say I have a service (XYZ.exe) installed of .NET v2.0. I make a change to the code and produce another executable of the same name **but with .NET v4.6.1** and replace the existing executable (after stopping the service). When I re-start the service, will the service use the new executable (.NET v4.6.1) or does it have a pre-loaded code of the old executable (.NET v2.0) which it uses?

Comment: The executable will use the version of the framework that was targeted when it was built.  So if you build it in 4.6.1, that's the version it will be.

Comment: With @Tim 's response - you should see that your app.config (exe.config) is updated to reflect the appropriate .NET version in the supported runtime.  There are other factors though depending on if your code is actually targeting specific files and libraries with file paths (a no-no, but possible).

Comment: Again, guys, I know all this. But this is for the executable. I need to know if changing the executable will make any change to the code used by the service.

Comment: I don't think you're properly explaining your real question.  Are you worried that "restart" doesn't unload the executable code from memory?  That services keep a cached copy of the file and won't use the file you replace?  That the service metadata remembers the .NET version and tries to use the old version instead of the one referenced by the new assembly?  Have you actually seen the wrong version loaded, or are you trying to prepare for trouble?

Comment: Plain and simple. Given any windows service, without thinking about restarting the computer or whatever, how do you know what version of .NET does the service use? Assume that the executable gets changed regularly, so you cannot trust the version of the executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think this is the answer. I'd be happy if someone reviews it.

We can go into the registry down to this level:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\eventlog\Application\<your_service_name>`

Then, we look into the value for the key `EventMessageFile` and it will show you the .NET version for the installed service.

**EDIT:**

This registry entry will be present only if the Windows service is installed using `InstallUtil.exe`. If however the Windows service was installed using `SC.exe`, then the registry entry will be present under:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\<your_service_name>`

Answer (score 1):

right click the related DLL and find its version in the properties.
Also if you are developing - so watch out the DLL probably will be loaded from the GAC and not from your DLL

Comment: Ok so just to be clear, even if I change the executable, it will not reflect any change on the actual service until I make a change on the GAC.

Comment: It depends - but mostly yes, you need to register your dll into the GAC. if it s a service - lookup in services which dll it is based upon and than check its version using the properties ( right click) - probably you will se it is still 2.0

Comment: What if the service is not on GAC? I can't find my service anywhere on GAC using gacutil. Am I missing something? Maybe I'm referring to the wrong GAC.